# How to order a set of strings by typeset length

Tags: xetex

I wish to be able to provide a set of strings (with formatting) and have them sorted in order of the final typeset length.  In my specific case, the shortest first. (the example uses arbitrary fonts that are hopefully commonly available)  Note: the results would be used as the text of a tikz node.

I am producing the content of the tex file from python, which would allow an initial ordering by the number of printed chars (eliminating the formatting content), but that does not take into consideration the attributes of the fonts.

An example (sorted by first char):

```
%19 chars of text
{\large\textbf Cellophane Tape Day}\par
%29 chars of text
{\miniscule Saturday Sixth Week Of Easter}\par
%50 chars of text
{\miniscule\bday{} {{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Greek]{Comic Sans MS}Σωκράτης Κόκκαλης}} ["{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Latin]{Impact}Sokratis Kokkalis, 1939CE}}"]}\par
%46 chars of text (including RTL and LTR
{\miniscule{\RL{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Arabic]{Courier New}\char"200Fرمضان\char"200E}} [{{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Calibri}}Ramaḍān Hilāl}} "{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Latin]{Impact}1st day of Ramadan}}"]}\par
%39 chars of text
{\miniscule\bday{} {{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase]{SimHei}唐德宗}} ["{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Latin]{Impact}Emperor Dezong of Tang, 742CE}}"]}\par
```

In the pic, the unordered is above the yellow line, the ideal ordering (for the example) is below the yellow line.  stackexchange would not allow me to attach 2 separate pics.

[image]

By manually rearranging the order of the lines, I can get the desired order, but the overall solution that would include this functionality would be creating files with hundreds of sets based on calculated inputs.  As a result, manual ordering is not particularly viable.

MWE that generates the first (unsorted) image:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openany,showtrimmarks]{memoir}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\font\bdayfont="Webdings" at 12pt
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bday}[1]{{\bdayfont \XeTeXglyph72}}
%19 chars of text
{\large\textbf Cellophane Tape Day}\par
%29 chars of text
{\miniscule Saturday Sixth Week Of Easter}\par
%50 chars of text
{\miniscule\bday{} {{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Greek]{Comic Sans MS}Σωκράτης Κόκκαλης}} ["{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Latin]{Impact}Sokratis Kokkalis, 1939CE}}"]}\par
%46 chars of text (including RTL and LTR
{\miniscule{\RL{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Arabic]{Courier New}\char"200Fرمضان\char"200E}} [{{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Calibri}}Ramaḍān Hilāl}} "{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Latin]{Impact}1st day of Ramadan}}"]}\par
%39 chars of text
{\miniscule\bday{} {{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase]{SimHei}唐德宗}} ["{{\fontspec[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Latin]{Impact}Emperor Dezong of Tang, 742CE}}"]}\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an implementation with `expl3` (together with an example of how you can use it in `\foreach`).

The idea is to absorb the items to sort by length, then measure them and store the width together with the index in a sequence; every item will be `{<dimen>}{<number>}`. Then we can sort the sequence with respect to the first part with `\dim_compare:nNnTF` (which does expansion on the first and third argument in order to find a length, so `\use_i:nn` will extract the first part). Once sorted this sequence, we can load another sequence with the items indexed by the second part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sortbylength}{mm}
 {
  \eirikr_sortlen:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getitem}{mm}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_eirikr_sortlen_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getnumber}{m}
 {
  \seq_count:c { g_eirikr_sortlen_#1_seq }
 }

\int_new:N \l__eirikr_sortlen_index_int
\box_new:N \l__eirikr_sortlen_temp_box
\seq_new:N \l__eirikr_sortlen_data_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \eirikr_sortlen:nn
 {
  % split the items into a sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__eirikr_sortlen_input_seq { | } { #2 }
  % typeset each item and store its width and the index
  \int_zero:N \l__eirikr_sortlen_index_int
  \seq_clear:N \l__eirikr_sortlen_data_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__eirikr_sortlen_input_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__eirikr_sortlen_index_int
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__eirikr_sortlen_temp_box { ##1 }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__eirikr_sortlen_data_seq
     {
      { \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l__eirikr_sortlen_temp_box } }
      { \int_eval:n { \l__eirikr_sortlen_index_int } }
     }
   }
  % sort the obtained items by the first part
  \seq_sort:Nn \l__eirikr_sortlen_data_seq
   {
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \use_i:nn ##1 } > { \use_i:nn ##2 }
     { \sort_return_swapped: }
     { \sort_return_same: }
   }
  % prepare a sequence with the (non typeset) items
  \seq_gclear_new:c { g_eirikr_sortlen_#1_seq }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__eirikr_sortlen_data_seq
   {
    \seq_gput_right:cx { g_eirikr_sortlen_#1_seq }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \l__eirikr_sortlen_input_seq { \use_ii:nn ##1 }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sortbylength{test}{
  abc |
  aabbcc |
  1234567890 |
  a
}

The list \texttt{test} has \getnumber{test} items. Here they are:

\foreach \x in {1,...,\getnumber{test}}
 {
  \getitem{test}{\x}\par
 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the example we get for the first sequence

```
The sequence \l__eirikr_sortlen_input_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {abc}
>  {aabbcc}
>  {1234567890}
>  {a}
```

Then the sequence with the lengths

```
The sequence \l__eirikr_sortlen_data_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {{15.27782pt}{1}}
>  {{30.27785pt}{2}}
>  {{50.00015pt}{3}}
>  {{5.00002pt}{4}}
```

and the sorted sequence is

```
The sequence \l__eirikr_sortlen_data_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {{5.00002pt}{4}}
>  {{15.27782pt}{1}}
>  {{30.27785pt}{2}}
>  {{50.00015pt}{3}}
```

And, to end the job, the final sequence built from the indices:

```
The sequence \g_eirikr_sortlen_test_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {abc}
>  {aabbcc}
>  {1234567890}
```